# How to put my Amazon EC2 project on hold

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've been using Amazon EC2 for a year but due to the lack of traffic I'm thinking of putting this site down for a while. I don't want to delete the whole thing, I just want to put it on hold for about five months.

I don't want my project to be gone forever and I have to do the work again. 
How can I put it on hold?

Comment: just create snapshots of the instances, and terminate them.

Comment: Create an AMI rather than a Snapshot. An AMI can be used when launching a new instance in future, while snapshots take more work to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the EC2 instance and keep the EBS Volume or Create a Snapshot. Later you start the server or re-create it using the EBS Snapshot. Storage cost will be only applied to you which is cheaper compared to the EC2 pricing.

> - Amazon EBS General Purpose SSD (gp2) volumes
>
>   - **$0.10 per GB-month of provisioned storage**
> - Amazon EBS Provisioned IOPS SSD (io1) volumes
>
>   - **$0.125 per GB-month of provisioned storage**
>   - **$0.065 per provisioned IOPS-month**
> - Amazon EBS Throughput Optimized HDD (st1) volumes
>
>   - **$0.045 per GB-month of provisioned storage**
> - Amazon EBS Cold HDD (sc1) volumes
>
>   - **$0.025 per GB-month of provisioned storage**
> - Amazon EBS Snapshots to Amazon S3
>
>   - **$0.05 per GB-month of data stored**

Note: The cost varies slightly based on the region and for region specific pricing check [this](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/) link.

If you plan to download the EBS Volume to your On-Premise environment to reduce EBS Volume/ Snapshot pricing, check out [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=151285) forum thread.